# char vs. wchar_t vs. char16_t vs. char32_t

Tags: c++, char

Can someone explain to me why all these different chars were created? I'm new to programming and I have trouble understanding all the jargons in different posts to explain this.

So far I understand that char was to small to fit all the other characters that are not included in the ASCII code. So people created the other 3 char types. Is that true? And what does it mean that wchar_t is dependant on the locale?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character

Comment: Have you read __Character types__:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types ?

Comment: The one thing you're going to learn very quickly is that characters should be simple but in practice are far more complicated than you'd expect. Just as "a" is a character, so is "à" and "å" and "".

Comment: There's also `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` - which are *3 distinct types*. And then there's UTF-8 (and 7), UTF-16, UTF-32, `std::string`, `gstring`, `QString` and many more. It's a complicated mess.

Comment: you might learn more than you want to know about character representation reading http://utf8everywhere.org/